# Probability of Generating a Connected Graph on the Unit Square

Tags: probability, graph-theory

$N$ points are generated randomly on the unit square, with a uniform distribution. What is the probability that they form a connected graph, given that two points are connected iff the distance between them is less than or equal to $d\in(0,\sqrt{2})$?

This should obviously be some function of $N$ and $d$.

Comment: Instead of a graph, one can think of this as generating discs of diameter $d$ with center in the unit square, and asking if the union forms a connected figure. Sounds difficult

Comment: These references are far from answering the question but might be of interest: 

http://www.ima.umn.edu/preprints/Jan83Dec83/34.pdf 

http://www.scipress.org/e-library/rpf/pdf/chap4/0197.PDF

Comment: I agree with leonbloy that this is likely to be a difficult question.  I think it's a great one, though, and would love to know the answer, too.

Comment: An exact probability is almost certainly impossible.  The first spot I'd check would probably be the classic random graph papers, Erdős (http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1959-11.pdf) and possibly Flajolet-Knuth-Pittel, "The First Cycles In An Evolving Graph" (to get a better sense for some of the analytical tools).  Obviously this problem has some structural correlation that pure random-graph problems don't, but that would at least be a starting point.

Comment: @anon: The problem is that those random variables are _not_ IID - for small $d$, if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are close enough to each other, then the probability that $p_n$ is 'close enough' to $p_2$ is highly correlated with the probability that it's 'close enough' to $p_1$.

Comment: @Steven: Ah, you're right.

Comment: @leonbloy: Such processes are often called *mosaic processes* and the study of such questions is part of the field. Usually $N$ (in the notation of the OP) is not fixed, but rather the outcome of a Poisson random variable.

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76153/probability-of-generating-a-connected-graph

Comment: **Related**: P. Hall (1986): [Clump counts in a mosaic](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176992525), *Ann. Prob.*, vol. 14, no. 2, 424-458.

Answer (score 3):

Let's brute force it.  Start with code for [Kruskal's algorithm](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConnectingTownsUsingKruskalsAlgorithm/), and then select a number of points (like 10), and find the maximal distance required by Kruskal over 10000 trials.  With 10 points, 20 points, and 30 points, I got figures like the following:

[image: maximal Kruskal distance on 10, 20, 30 points]

Here's code for the 30 point image.

```
Histogram[Table[Max[With[{pts = RandomReal[{0,1},{30,2}]},
EuclideanDistance[pts[[#]][[1]],pts[[#]][[2]]]&/@List@@@Kruskal[pts]]],{10000}]]
```

Looks like you could fit a distribution curve to those pretty easily.  But that's beyond the duties of a brute forcer, so I'll stop there.